# Are JSGI and `http.createServer()` in node.js two alternative ways for executing a server side JavaScript web application?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I see that we can write a server side web application in JavaScript without framework, by using `http.createServer()` from https://medium.com/@saurabhkumar_4718/a-simple-nodejs-server-without-express-js-6773122d365f

I also see from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSGI

> JSGI, or JavaScript Gateway Interface, is an interface between web servers and JavaScript-based web applications and frameworks

Are there two methods alternative to each other, both for executing a server side JavaScript web application? Or are they used for different purposes, and can  work together?

Why do we need JSGI when we can achieve the same by creating a server by `http.createServer()`?

Comment: JSGI seems pretty outdated. And it's just a different interface for the application, when you actually run it on node.js [then it uses `http.createServer`](https://github.com/kriszyp/jsgi-node/blob/master/jsgi-node.js#L249) as well.

Comment: why 
JSGI seems pretty outdated?  what was it used for and with, if not node.s?

Comment: The Wikipedia article is about 5 years old, and the node-jsgi framework doesn't seem to have much developed since. I've never seen it used anywhere. And the CommonJS standard (or is it still a draft) hasn't seen work since 2010.

Comment: Thanks. Is Express.js implmented based on http.createServer()?

Comment: I'd guess so, but you can quickly find out by checking the source

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in the comment `JSGI` is old and very low-level **interface between a HTTP server and JavaScript-based web applications**. I personally have never came cross any node.js code that uses `JSGI`. you can use `http.createServer()` to run your http server in nodejs but you then have to take care of a lot of things such as parsing the requests and responses. You also don't need `JSGI` when using `http.createServer()`

a better (more practical,modern and high-level) way to run web server on nodejs is to use [express](https://expressjs.com/) or [koa](https://koajs.com/).